# Laravel adding parameter with raw queries using Like operators and '%"

Tags: php, laravel

I did some ways to assign parameter but it's not working

Here is my code:

```
$sqlDefault = "Select * from histories as h where h.status like % :status %";

return DB::select(DB::raw($sqlDefault), ['status' => $status]);
```

It's not working so I try another ways to assign:

`'%:status%'` or `'%':status'%'`

But it's not work

Now I don't use parameter and it's worked perfectlly

`$sqlDefault = "Select * from histories as h where h.status like '%$status%'";`

The question is how I can use parameter when using like operator with "%" ?

Answer (score 7):

Replace `$status` with `'%'.$status.'%'`

```
$sqlDefault = "Select * from histories as h where h.status like  :status ";

return DB::select(DB::raw($sqlDefault,['status' => '%'.$status.'%']));
```

or just use select only:

```
return  = DB::select(sqlDefault , ['status' => '%'.$status.'%']);
```

Answer (score 4):

Prepared statement's placeholder doesn't work within `'%...%'` because it then considered as a `string` value instead of `placeholder`. You've to put placeholder directly and then pass the value including `"%{$variable}%"`.

Try this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `histories` AS h WHERE `h`.`status` LIKE :status";

return DB::select($sql, [ 'status' => "%{$status}%" ]);
```

Comment: Thanks for kind reply but it's still show nothing.
When I change  `$sql = "SELECT * FROM `histories` WHERE `status` LIKE :status";` and search with right value, it's worked
In my situation I use join function so I it's is ``histories.status``, is it riight?

Comment: @VuHoangDuc Happy to help :-) Also, if any answer helped you then please tick mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check what queries were run, you may use `dd(DB::getQueryLog())`.

Try this:

```
$result = DB::table('histories')->where('status', 'like', '%' . $status . '%')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this without assign parameters

```
DB::table('histories')
  ->where('status' , 'like', '%'. $status .%' )
  ->get();
```

Or you can use direct histories app class like this

Add `use App/Histories;` on the top

And use query like this

```
Histories::where('status' , 'like', '%'. $status .%' )->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using it now but I want to find solution for assign parameter with %